# Pandas expanding a dataframe's length and populating every nth row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns that I'm interested in which looks like this:

```
    frame   requests
0   0   214388438.0
1   1   194980303.0
2   2   179475934.0
3   3   165196540.0
4   4   154815540.0
5   5   123650671.0
6   6   119089045.0
```

This goes on for many rows. So what I'm looking for is a way to keep the value on the `requests` column then add rows filled with 0 and repeat the process for a certain amount of rows. `frame` column would also have to be updated accordingly.

Now what I need is to adjust this dataframe so that I have in the following manner:

```
        frame   requests
    0   0   214388438.0
    1   0             0
    2   0             0
    3   0             0
    4   0             0
    5   0             0
    6   0             0
   ....................
   47   0             0
   48   1   194980303.0
   49   1             0
   ....................
```

The thing is the dataframe is only 48 rows long but it could be longer like 200 or more so it would have to take that into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and then duplicated values set to `0`:

```
N = 3
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(N)]
df['requests'] = df['requests'].mask(df.index.duplicated(), 0)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    frame     requests
0       0  214388438.0
1       0          0.0
2       0          0.0
3       1  194980303.0
4       1          0.0
5       1          0.0
6       2  179475934.0
7       2          0.0
8       2          0.0
9       3  165196540.0
10      3          0.0
11      3          0.0
12      4  154815540.0
13      4          0.0
14      4          0.0
15      5  123650671.0
16      5          0.0
17      5          0.0
18      6  119089045.0
19      6          0.0
20      6          0.0
```

Comment: Awesome. Another thing, what if I wanted to offset the position of the value on the requests and even preserve 
For example, where frame = 1 the first value on requests should be value before, then comes the value followed by 0, and where frame =2 the first two values on requests should be the previous two values, then comes the value then followed by 0. Is that possible?

Comment: @Geosphere - do you need `df = pd.concat([df['requests'].iloc[:i].append(pd.Series({-1:0})) for i, x in enumerate(df.index, 1)], ignore_index=True)` ?

Comment: No, not like that. Also, I would still need it to be a dataframe instead of a series. Maybe it would be better to open another question.

Comment: @Geosphere - good idea ;)

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72126459/pandas-expanding-a-dataframe-length-but-populate-each-row-incrementally-based-on