# Pandas expanding a dataframe length but populate each row incrementally based on column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    frame   requests
0   0   214388438.0
1   1   194980303.0
2   2   179475934.0
3   3   165196540.0
4   4   154815540.0
5   5   123650671.0
6   6   119089045.0
```

The thing is I want to add each of the value found on the requests column incrementally.
Say frame 0 should have the first value, frame 1 should have the previous value and the one that comes after followed by 0. I want the dataframe to look something like this:

```
        frame   requests
    0   0   214388438.0
    1   0             0
    2   0             0
    3   0             0
   ....................
   48   1   214388438.0
   49   1   194980303.0
   50   1             0
   ....................
   ..   2   214388438.0
   ..   2   194980303.0
   ..   2   179475934.0
   ..   2             0
```

Eventually, on the last value for column `frame` all rows would be populated by the value on the requests, no more 0s.

```
   ....................
   ..   47   214388438.0
   ..   47   194980303.0
   ..   47   179475934.0
   ..   47   165196540.0
   ..   47   154815540.0
   ..   47   123650671.0
   .....................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `df` as input, you can use numpy to reshape and create a new DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np

a = df['requests'].to_numpy()

df2 = (pd
 .DataFrame(np.tril(np.tile(a, (len(a), 1))), index=df['frame'])
 .stack()
 .droplevel(1)
 .reset_index(name='requests')
)
```

*NB. You can also use `df['requests']` directly instead of `a`, the conversion to array will be done automatically.*

output:

```
    frame     requests
0       0  214388438.0
1       0          0.0
2       0          0.0
3       0          0.0
4       0          0.0
5       0          0.0
6       0          0.0
7       1  214388438.0
8       1  194980303.0
9       1          0.0
10      1          0.0
11      1          0.0
12      1          0.0
13      1          0.0
14      2  214388438.0
15      2  194980303.0
16      2  179475934.0
17      2          0.0
18      2          0.0
19      2          0.0
20      2          0.0
21      3  214388438.0
22      3  194980303.0
23      3  179475934.0
24      3  165196540.0
25      3          0.0
26      3          0.0
27      3          0.0
28      4  214388438.0
29      4  194980303.0
30      4  179475934.0
31      4  165196540.0
32      4  154815540.0
33      4          0.0
34      4          0.0
35      5  214388438.0
36      5  194980303.0
37      5  179475934.0
38      5  165196540.0
39      5  154815540.0
40      5  123650671.0
41      5          0.0
42      6  214388438.0
43      6  194980303.0
44      6  179475934.0
45      6  165196540.0
46      6  154815540.0
47      6  123650671.0
48      6  119089045.0
```